# Problem when rending a flextable to Beamer presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, flextable, beamer

I encountered similar issues in [this post](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/428#issuecomment-1192784206) when rendering a flextable in a Beamer presentation.

Surprisingly, it worked fine for all other document formats like Word, PDF, PPTX, and HTML, except for Beamer. And I can also knit everything to beamer (text, figure, tables by kable), except a flextable.

So the problem is only at knitting a felxtable to beamer presentation. Example codes:

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
  pdf_document: default
  powerpoint_presentation: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flextable)
```

## Slide
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
example_ft <-
  iris |> head() |> 
  flextable()
example_ft
```
````

Every attempt to debug the problem was unsuccessful, despite trying the following steps:

1. Re-installing/Updating R.
2. Re-installing/Updating R Studio.
3. Re-installing/Updating all the packages.
4. Restarting the R session.
5. Following the debugging instructions provided in the error below.

Unfortunately, the issue persists and the error message continues to appear.

#### Update: I tried this Rmd file on three computers, 2 Mac Pro (1 intel, 1 M1) and 1 Dell, and they all showed the same error below.

> processing file: test2.Rmd
>
> /usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test2.knit.md --to beamer --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test2.tex --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --embed-resources --standalone
> output file: test2.knit.md
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  \Oldarrayrulewidth
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile test2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test2.log for more info.
> Execution halted

I would appreciate it if you could give me any solution for this.

My session information:

> sessionInfo()

> R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
> Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Monterey 12.3
>
> Matrix products: default
> BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
>
> locale:
> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> time zone: Asia/Tokyo
> tzcode source: internal
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] gtsummary_1.7.1       kableExtra_1.3.4.9000 lubridate_1.9.2       forcats_1.0.0         stringr_1.5.0
> [6] dplyr_1.1.2           purrr_1.0.1           readr_2.1.4           tidyr_1.3.0           tibble_3.2.1
> [11] ggplot2_3.4.2         tidyverse_2.0.0       flextable_0.9.2
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] tidyselect_1.2.0        viridisLite_0.4.2       fastmap_1.1.1           xaringan_0.28           fontquiver_0.2.1
> [6] broom.helpers_1.13.0    promises_1.2.0.1        digest_0.6.33           timechange_0.2.0        mime_0.12
> [11] lifecycle_1.0.3         ellipsis_0.3.2          gfonts_0.2.0            processx_3.8.2          magrittr_2.0.3
> [16] compiler_4.3.1          sass_0.4.6              rlang_1.1.1             tools_4.3.1             gt_0.9.0
> [21] utf8_1.2.3              yaml_2.3.7              data.table_1.14.8       knitr_1.43              askpass_1.1
> [26] prettyunits_1.1.1       htmlwidgets_1.6.2       pkgbuild_1.4.2          curl_5.0.1              xml2_1.3.5
> [31] rsconnect_0.8.29        pkgload_1.3.2.1         httpcode_0.3.0          miniUI_0.1.1.1          withr_2.5.0
> [36] grid_4.3.1              fansi_1.0.4             urlchecker_1.0.1        profvis_0.3.8           gdtools_0.3.3
> [41] xtable_1.8-4            colorspace_2.1-0        scales_1.2.1            crul_1.4.0              tinytex_0.45
> [46] cli_3.6.1               rmarkdown_2.23          crayon_1.5.2            ragg_1.2.5              generics_0.1.3
> [51] remotes_2.4.2           rstudioapi_0.15.0       httr_1.4.6              tzdb_0.4.0              sessioninfo_1.2.2
> [56] cachem_1.0.8            rvest_1.0.3             vctrs_0.6.3             devtools_2.4.5          webshot_0.5.5
> [61] jsonlite_1.8.7          fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 xaringanthemer_0.4.2    callr_3.7.3             hms_1.1.3
> [66] systemfonts_1.0.4       jquerylib_0.1.4         glue_1.6.2              ps_1.7.5                DT_0.28
> [71] stringi_1.7.12          gtable_0.3.3            later_1.3.1             munsell_0.5.0           pillar_1.9.0
> [76] htmltools_0.5.5         openssl_2.0.6           R6_2.5.1                textshaping_0.3.6       evaluate_0.21
> [81] shiny_1.7.4.1           memoise_2.0.1           bslib_0.5.0             fontLibera

Every attempt to debug the problem was unsuccessful, despite trying the following steps:

Re-installing/Updating R.
Re-installing/Updating R Studio.
Re-installing/Updating all the packages.
Restarting the R session.
Following the debugging instructions provided in the error below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to this same problem recently when I tried running my script on a new computer. I found the issue is related to versioning of the flextable package. I had been running 0.6.6 on my old computer and obviously updated to the latest version on the new machine. I "solved" the problem by copying the 0.6.6 version from my old machine to the new one. It's not the ideal solution, and it doesn't explain the cause of the problem, but it's holding me over for now.

I used `packageVersion("flextable")` to find my version, and `.libPath()` to learn where my packages were stored so I could replace new with old.

Comment: **Wow, it worked! Many thanks!**  
It could suggest that the bug is probably in the newer version of *flextable*.  
Here is all the code that I used to load the older version of *flextable*:  
`require(devtools)`   
`install_version("flextable", version = "0.6.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`   
`detach("package:flextable", unload = TRUE)`   
`library(flextable)`

Comment: Although it's written in the original ticket (https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/428), I'd like to re-specify that you're getting an image and not a latex board. The ticket is called "Add Beamer to Flextable's Supported Formats?" because it doesn't work with beamer, it's a known problem that hasn't been solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Rmarkdown uses commands from packages it does not load and also uses totally made up macros, which it would need to define first.

Here a minimum fix to get it to at least compile ... the output is not necessary pretty, though...

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \usepackage{hhline}
  \newlength\Oldarrayrulewidth
  \newlength\Oldtabcolsep
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{array}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flextable)
set_flextable_defaults(fonts_ignore=TRUE)
```

## Slide {.fragile}
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
example_ft <-
  iris |> head() |> 
  flextable()
example_ft
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt help. I did try your solution, it helped to compile the beamer but did not help in making a nice table for the presentation. In this [post](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/428#issuecomment-1192784206), davidgohel successfully run the example code on his computer. So I was wondering if there is a bug either in flextable or TinyTex?

Comment: @papa_phuong No idea, you would need to ask somebody who actually knows rmarkdown.